# Does a never claim prove a Linear Temporal Logic formula?

Tags: logic, formula, proof

I have an LTL formula, that was automatically generated from a program I used:

```
    (((a))&&F((((b))&&F((c)))))
```

which reads as

```
    a && F(b && Fc)
```

I then used the ltl2BA-win.exe program downloaded from here:
[LTL 2 BA](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/ltl2ba/index.php) and got a never claim as output. The website can also generate a Büchi Automaton for an LTL formula (I left the "Use Spin Syntax" and "Use Spin 4.3.0" options unchecked when using this site).

My questions are: 
1. Is it the never claim that proves the LTL formula or the fact that a Büchi Automaton was produced? 
2. Is a never claim on its own enough to prove an LTL formula or does the never claim need feeding into a model checker, such as Spin, for extra processing to provide the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further reading I found answers that give me a clearer picture regarding the purpose of never claims and Büchi automata here: [The Model Checker Spin](http://spinroot.com/spin/Doc/ieee97.pdf) and [Temporal Claims](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~muffy/MRS4-2002/lect14.ppt).

According to this literature, just by establishing the presence or absence of a never claim is enough to prove or disprove the LTL formula.